# GCC error: cannot convert 'const shared_ptr<...>' to 'bool' in return

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I'm switching to GCC 4.6.1, and it starts to complain about code which works fine with GCC 4.4 and MSVC10. It seems that it doesn't want to convert between `shared_ptr` and `bool` when returning from a function like this:

```
class Class { shared_ptr<Somewhere> pointer_; };

bool Class::Function () const
{
    return pointer_;
}
```

using

```
return static_cast<bool> (pointer_);
```

everything works. What the heck is going on? This is with `--std=cpp0x`.

Comment: Why the heck would you want to do this?

Comment: To check if the pointer has been set.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In C++11, `shared_ptr` has an `explicit` `operator bool` which means that a `shared_ptr` can't be implicitly converted to a `bool`.

This is to prevent some potentially pitfalls where a `shared_ptr` might accidentally be converted in arithmetic expressions and the similar situations.

Adding an explicit cast is a valid fix to your code.

You could also do `return pointer_.get() != 0;`, `return pointer_.get();` or even `return pointer_ != nullptr;`.

Comment: @LucDanton: For no rational reason, I completely dislike that method but yes, it also works.

Comment: To be quite honest I mentioned it because it preceded explicit conversions operators and contextual conversions.

Comment: @LucDanton If you like obfuscation, yes.  What you'd really like to write is either `return pointer != NULL;` or `return pointer.is_valid();` or something similar.  Regretfully, neither Boost nor the standards committee decided to support this, so your stuck with `return pointer.get() != NULL'`.

Comment: Sorry for the long kick. Why not return pointer_.is_initialized() ?

Answer (score 3):

shared_ptr has an [explicit bool conversion](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2435.htm). It can be used in a conditional expression or can be explicitly converted to bool as you did with static_cast.